# Installation of Heroku returns errors with json

Tags: software-installation, heroku

Like the title says, I've been trying to install Heroku. However, as soon as I run any heroku commands I get this in return:

```
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator='
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

I ran these commands to install Heroku:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu ./'
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
 sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? Can you get the version from `heroku version`? If not what is the output of `apt-cache policy heroku-toolbelt`?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and the output of `apt-cache policy heroku-toolbelt` is 3.9.4.

Comment: Try to do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. I am on 14.04 also, my installed version is 3.9.5 and it runs fine.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick thanks! Mind putting your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with version 3.9.4 of Heroku ToolBelt.

As there is a new version available it should be fixed with a update:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or if you only want to update that package

```
$ sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt
```