# Serial port permissions in Ubuntu Core 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, ubuntu-core, serial-port

I have installed Ubuntu Core 16.04 (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-135-generic x86_64) in a industrial PC Dell. I'm running Node-Red and now I need to connect serial ports to be read on the PC.

When run node-red displays this error:

```
2018-11-02T11:49:19Z node-red.node-red[4692]: 2 Nov 11:49:19 - 
[error] serial port /dev/ttyACM0 error: Error:
Error: Permission denied, cannot open /dev/ttyACM0
```

I'd try to set ttyACM0 in a group (called QR) saved in `/home/admin`, typing this:

```
root@4LVL902:/home/admin# ln -s -T /dev/ttyACM0 QR
root@4LVL902:/home/admin# ls
QR  images  node-red_0.19.4_amd64.snap  snap
```

But the problem is the same:

```
2018-11-02T11:41:32Z node-red.node-red[4692]: 2 Nov 11:41:32 - 
[error] serial port /home/admin/QR error: Error:
Error: Permission denied, cannot open /home/admin/QR`
```

I know it's a permission problem, but I'm new to Ubuntu and don't know how to solve it. What folders or files have node-red permission? Do I have to put the QR group under node-red folder? node-red is installed in `home/admin`.

Also one of the devices has to install drivers (RS232) to work, but don't know how to do this on Ubuntu Core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find serial port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631601/how-to-find-serial-port)

Comment: I've modified the question, now I have my serial port located but it's a permissions problem between node-red and the serial. Also, command "setserial" doesn't work in Ubuntu Core (or doesn't work for me...).

Comment: Then you need to add your user to `dialout` group with `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`.