# Unable to install Heroku

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ssl, heroku

I'm trying to install Heroku on Ubuntu 16.04  following the instructions from the official website but after the command `sudo apt-get update` I'm getting the following errors :

```
Err:30 https://cliassets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ Packages SSL: certificate subject name (*.herokuapp.com) does not match target host name 'cliassets.heroku.com'
Ign:31 https://cliassets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:32 https://cliassets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ Translation-en
Fetched 4,351 kB in 22s (192 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://cliassets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://cliassets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt/ ./ Packages  SSL: certificate subject name (*.herokuapp.com) does not match target host name 'cliassets.heroku.com'
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've looked through other answers and solution but didn't help. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you update your post to provide the link with the instructions you are following?

Comment: Please use the `{}` button in the edtor to format terminal output.

Comment: It a problem on Heroku  server-side. Try to contact them.

Comment: To whoever the close voter is who thinks that Heroku is off topic: Read the `heroku` tag under the question.

Comment: Adding addition information to @N0bert

It seems to be a problem with the Heroku's SSL certificate. Try to find a solution using herokuapp.com instead, or if no solution contact Heroku.

Comment: Duplicate of this [Installation of Heroku returns errors with json](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500921/installation-of-heroku-returns-errors-with-json). Also use the other repo: toolbelt.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 3):

To install heroku in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install snapd    
sudo snap install heroku --classic
```

This installs the heroku snap package (version 6.15 which is currently the latest version) successfully, and it is the recommended way of installing Heroku CLI in Ubuntu at the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) website.